# use of filter_input_array and array_filter on the same array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a variable set of identical input fields in my form where some can be empty.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="option[]" placeholder="fill in" />
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="option[]" placeholder="optional" />
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="option[]" placeholder="optional" />
```

the values of these input fields come into the array `$_POST["option"]`

I want to filter `$_POST["option"]` and for that I am using the following code:

```
$filter = array("option" => array("filter"=>FILTER_CALLBACK,"flags"=>FILTER_FORCE_ARRAY,"options"=>"ucwords"));
$optionfin = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, $filter);
```

But now I want to also use the `array_filter` function to remove the empty fields so I can INPUT only the filled in fields into my database but this doesn't seem to work.

```
$option = array_filter($optionfin);
```

when I do the following:

```
$optionfin = array_filter($_POST["option"]);
```

this is working fine, but i know you better not access the `$_POST` this way because it isn't that safe...

Can anyone help me to point out where i am going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: `$newvar = $_POST['option'];` and then do `$optionfin = array_filter($newvar);`

Comment: In that way it works i know, i allready mentioned that in my original question here. But i want to filter on strings and integers to. So i would like to use `filter_input_array` for that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are using `filter_input_array`, you will actually end up with an associative array that corresponds to `$_POST`. So to filter out empty fields as you are trying to do, you will need to specify the `option` key:

```
$option = array_filter($optionfin['option']);
```

Comment: Thanks that did the trick! Shame of me that is did not tought about that myself!